# Disable Vibration iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-vibrate

Is there a way to disable the vibration of iPhone programmatically?

All I could find is how to enable the vibration. Basically I want to toggle the `Vibration Mode` through `UISwitch`.

Can anybody help me out if there's a way to do that?

Comment: Why do you want/need to do that?

Comment: I don't think this can be done. And for good reason: don't override the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know you can't do this . Because apple not allowing these kind of functions .